# Start Process from Service hung UseShellExecute false

Tags: c#, service, backgroundworker

I run into a strange thing and can't find the reason why this is happening.

I have a service.exe where I collect data from configuration registry and then start n processes.

Sample Code:

```
_mProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
  FileName = Command,
  Arguments = Argument,
  WorkingDirectory = WorkDir
};
_mProcess.Start();
Pid = _mProcess.Id;
```

My `Pid` contains the process id.

Now I added `UseShellExecute = false` to get the StandardOutput.

New sample code:

```
_mProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
  FileName = Command,
  Arguments = Argument,
  WorkingDirectory = WorkDir //,
  //CreateNoWindow = true,
  UseShellExecute = false,
  //RedirectStandardOutput = true,
  RedirectStandardError = true
  //RedirectStandardInput = true
};
_mProcess.Start();
Pid = _mProcess.Id;

using (var reader = _mProcess.StandardError)
{
  _logger.ToLog("", Company, reader.ReadToEnd(), "RCluster.log", "service");
}
```

In this case the process return back any error which I can store to my log file.

Problem: This code is part of a method to start a process which I call many times (depends on my configuration).
So with this code the first process is called, the following processes are not.
Somehow the service wait for the first service now. I thought this happens only with `WaitForExit`.

So how I can get standard error output but not make the process block my main task to continue?

Comment: Your process is waiting for the error reader to find the stream end, so it will block until the process has finished. Launch the error processing in another thread or async task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gusman: Add you comment as answer, you brought me to the correct answer. Then I can accept your comment as answer.

To the down-voter: Explanation why would be appreciated.

To all: I added some code to start the new process as a thread. In this case it make sense to start it in another thread to grab `StandardError messages but do not block the main process (which is a service in my case that starts many sub processes).

```
      // start as new thread to prevent blocking
      var ths = new ThreadStart(() =>
      {
        mProcess.Start();
        Pid = mProcess.Id;

        // write pid file
        File.WriteAllText(RubyDir + @"\tmp\pids\" + Port + @".pid", Pid.ToString());

        using (var reader = mProcess.StandardError)
        {
          var errorMsg = reader.ReadToEnd();
          if (errorMsg.Length > 0) _logger.ToLog("", Company, errorMsg, "SOLR.log", "service");
        }
      });
      var th = new Thread(ths);
      th.Start();
```